# Are JOINs and one to many type relationships related?

Tags: sql

Is there a relationship between the `JOIN` clauses used in in a `SELECT` statement and how the two tables are related to one another, i.e. one to many, many to one, one to one?  If not, can/should those type of table relationships be defined in SQL code?

Comment: No. There's no rule that columns you join on have to feature in any relationship defined on the tables.

Comment: you can add a foreign key if you want to enforce some sort of relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining these relationships is done by using Foreign Keys. These keys ensure referential integrity, by enforcing constraints on either side.

Example:

`table-one: id, name
table-many: id, name, table-one_id`

Here, `table-one_id` is a foreign key (referencing the id of table-one), ensuring you can only enter valid ids (present in table-one).

Defining FK's is not mandatory, but it provides referential integrity.

JOINs in SELECT statements are often done using these foreign keys. But it is not technically required or needed.

Comment: I've looked at w3schools.com's `JOIN` definitions but am still confused.  Is it true then that the type of `JOIN` clause, `INNER`, `LEFT` etc does _not_ imply a many to one, one to many, etc. relationship?

Comment: Correct, you merely join two tables (either fully, or partially - see the Venn diagrams at w3schools). No relationship is implied. Although in most cases we will join because there is a certain relationship between the tables. Good examples and clarification in Siyual's answer.

Comment: Thank you.  I could not find a definitive "does not apply" answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of questions here:

> Is there a relationship between the JOIN clauses used in in a SELECT statement and how the two tables are related to one another?

In the vast majority of cases, yes, a `JOIN` clause will illustrate one of the ways two tables are related to each other.  But this is not always the case.  Consider the two following examples:

1)

```
Select  *
From    TableA  A
Join    TableB  B   On  A.B_Id = B.Id
```

2)

```
Select  *
From    TableA      A
Join    @CodeList   B   On  A.Code = B.Code
```

In the first example `JOIN`, there is a defined relationship in the table between `TableA` and `TableB`.

However, in the second example, it is more likely that `@CodeList` is acting more as a *filter* for `TableA`. The `JOIN` in this situation is not over a defined relationship between the two tables, but rather a means to filter the data to a defined set.

So to answer your first question: a `JOIN` will usually indicate some kind of relationship between two tables, but its presence, alone, doesn't always mean that.

> Can/should those type of table relationships be defined in SQL code?

Not necessarily.  Even discounting the above example where there was no intended relationship between the tables for the `JOIN` condition, a defined `FOREIGN KEY` relationship is not always desirable.  One thing to keep in mind with `FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINTS` is that they are *`CONSTRAINTS`*.

Whether or not you wish to physically constrain your data to not allow values that violate the constraint is completely situational, based on your needs.

*Can* they?  Yes, they certainly can.

*Should* they?  Not always - it depends on your intention.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have formal PK/FK relationships to write joins. However, if you have those types of relationships, it is in your best interest to have them formalized from a data integrity view. Additionally, SQL server may create a better execution plan for the query when you already have these relationships. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647793.aspx

There is no advantage to not create PK/FK relationships.